# Gensim Doc2Vec Access Vectors by Document Author

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I have three documents in a df:

```
id    author    document
12X   john      the cat sat
12Y   jane      the dog ran
12Z   jane      the hippo ate
```

These documents are converted into a corpus of `TaggedDocuments` with the tags being the typical practice of semantically meaningless ints:

```
def read_corpus(documents):
    for i, plot in enumerate(documents):
        yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(plot, max_len=30), [i])

train_corpus = list(read_corpus(df.document))
```

This corpus is then used to train my `Doc2Vec` model:

```
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=55)
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

The resulting vectors of the model are accessed like this:

```
model.docvecs.vectors_docs
```

How would I tie the original df to the resulting vectors? Now that all the documents are trained and vectors are identified for each one, I want to query the set of vectors by author. For example, if I want to return a set of vectors only for Jane, how would I do so?

I think the basic idea is to identify the int tags that correspond to Jane and then do something like this to access them:

```
from operator import itemgetter 
a = model.docvecs.vectors_docs
b = [1, 2]
itemgetter(*b)(a)
```

How would I identify the tags though? They are only meaningful to the model and the tagged documents, so they don't join back to my original df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a simple example using Gensim. I think the approach here should work for you

```
import gensim
training_sentences = ['This is some document from Author {}'.format(i) for i in range(1,10)]
def read_corpus():
    for i,line in enumerate(training_sentences):
        # lets use the tag to identify the document and author
        yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), ['Doc{}_Author{}'.format(i,i)])
```

You could also directly prepare the training corpus from pandas_df like shown below

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'doc':training_sentences,'doc_id':[i for i in range (1,10)],'author_id':[10+i for i in range (1,10)]})
data_df.head()
tagged_docs = data_df.apply(lambda x:gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(x.doc),['doc{}_auth{}'.format(x.doc_id,x.author_id)]),axis=1)
training_corpus = tagged_docs.values

>> array([ TaggedDocument(words=['this', 'is', 'some', 'document', 'from', 'author'], tags=['doc1_auth11']),
       TaggedDocument(words=['this', 'is', 'some', 'document', 'from', 'author'], tags=['doc2_auth12']),

# training
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=55)
train_corpus = list(read_corpus())
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
# indexing
model.docvecs.index2entity

>>
['Doc0_Author0',
 'Doc1_Author1',
 'Doc2_Author2',
 'Doc3_Author3',
 'Doc4_Author4',
 'Doc5_Author5',
 'Doc6_Author6',
 'Doc7_Author7',
 'Doc8_Author8']
```

Now, to access the vector corresponding to document1 of author1, you could do

```
model.docvecs[model.docvecs.index2entity.index('Doc1_Author1')]

array([  8.08026362e-03,   4.27437993e-03,  -7.73820514e-03,
        -7.40669528e-03,   6.36066869e-03,   4.03292105e-03,
         9.60215740e-03,  -4.26750770e-03,  -1.34797185e-03,
        -9.02472902e-03,   6.25275355e-03,  -2.49505695e-03,
         3.18572600e-03,   2.56929174e-03,  -4.17032139e-03,
        -2.33384431e-03,  -5.10744564e-03,  -5.29057207e-03,
         5.41675789e-03,   5.83767192e-03,  -5.91145828e-03,
         5.91885624e-03,  -1.00465110e-02,   8.32535885e-03,
         9.72494949e-03,  -7.35746371e-03,  -1.86231872e-03,
         8.94813929e-05,  -4.11528209e-03,  -9.72509012e-03,
        -6.52212929e-03,  -8.83922912e-03,   9.46981460e-03,
        -3.90578934e-04,   6.74136635e-03,  -5.24599617e-03,
         9.73031297e-03,  -8.77021812e-03,  -5.55411633e-03,
        -7.21857697e-03,  -4.50362219e-03,  -4.06361837e-03,
         2.57276138e-03,   1.76626759e-06,  -8.08755495e-03,
        -1.48400548e-03,  -5.26673114e-03,  -7.78301107e-03,
        -4.24248137e-04,  -7.99000356e-03], dtype=float32)
```

yes this uses doc-author pair ordering, you could just use doc_id alone and maintain a separate index like `{doc_id:author_id}` in a python dict, if you want to filter by author then use `{author_id : [docids,...]}`

Comment: that makes sense intuitively, but i'm struggling to apply it to a pandas df - how would i apply `read_corpus` to the toy df so as to support multiple documents from an author?

Comment: loop through the rows in the df, if you are reading the df from a file chunk it

Comment: isn't that what my current code is doing? unsure of how to add the author tag to the mix. are you suggesting author should be set to the author string, or to an int?

Comment: ah i see now, you just need to pass the df row to the read_corpus instead of just documents

Comment: wouldn't that require `apply()`? how would that change the for loop in `read_corpus`? apologies - my brain is quite addled today

Comment: also, when accessing later on, wouldn't this only allow accessing by doc-author pair rather than just author?

Comment: thank you very much! it's starting to make more sense. could you please expand on the last point regarding filtering by author? where would that dict go?

Comment: @CameronTaylor you have to build and maintain it, everytime you train. You may need to pickle it as well.

Comment: if i just used doc_id as the tag (i.e. the 12X, 12Y, 12Z from my example), would the final block (itemgetter) be a good way to query by author? without maintaining that separate index?

Comment: hmm...but that is retrieving the vectors by index

Comment: You need an additional index if you just tag using document Id. No free lunch

Comment: are you suggesting building both dicts you mentioned, or just one or the other? i know i'm asking a lot, but if you have a moment, I would love to see what something like that looks like. this is all pretty new to me. marking the answer as correct regardless

Comment: @CameronTaylor I would build author to document Index and use document Id as tags in doc vectors